# Assign an event to community group

Tags: ektron

I have created an event in Ektron.How could I assign that event to a particular community group so that event can be visible only to that particular community group?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the permissions on the event. In the workarea content tab, open your event.  To the left of the "Edit content" button, you should see a "permissions" button. Once on the permissions screen, hit "edit permissions", and then "add permissions". Remove the "Everyone" group, and add the groups you want to be able to see your content. Finally, check the box near the top of the screen to mark the content as "private" in order to require a login.

If you anticipate creating many events with this set of permissions, instead apply these steps to a folder, and any content in that folder will have the applied permissions.

The ektron reference manual can walk you through either of these scenarios:
http://documentation.ektron.com/cms400/v802/WebHelp/Managing%20Folders/Folder%20Permissions/Permissions_intro.htm

Comment: We can set permission for Group or User,but cannot for Community groups

Comment: There should be a dropdown in the upper right of the permissions area (just below the action bar with the back, add permissions buttons, etc) that allows you to switch to membership users (and groups).